# Why does my function not accept the name of the argument which is of the type Colors?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a function in which an argument as to the colour name can be passed in, however this shows the following error:

```
The getter $colorName isn't defined for the type Colors
```

My function is as below:

```
void makeButton({Colors colorName, int soundNumber}) {     
    Container(
      color: Colors.$colorName,
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('Hello');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

What exactly is my mistake here?

Comment: Should be `Color` like `({Color colorName, int soundNumber}) ` .

Comment: Hey, @dev-aentgs, I tried that, don't think that's the right answer though!

Comment: What is the value being passed to `colorName` ?

Comment: The error arises when I'm defining the function itself; I intend to pass colour names such as 'red' and 'blue' into it if I can get it to work.
(Thanks for replying)

Comment: oh ok, you can try below approach. Passing `Colors.TargetColor` to the method.

Comment: Added code snippet with respect to your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very small snippet for passing `Color`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getContainer(colorName: Colors.yellow);
  }
  
  Widget getContainer({Color colorName}){
    return Container(
      color: colorName,
        child: Text('Hello, World!'));
  }
}
```

In the case of your example it would be

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return makeButton(colorName: Colors.yellow);
  }
  
Widget makeButton({Color colorName, int soundNumber}) {     
   return Container(
      color: colorName,
      child: FlatButton(
        child:Text('Flat Button'),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Hello');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Colors.target_color` returns a `Color` type.